# hp mini 1110nr best version of ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments, ubuntu-netbook

What version of Ubuntu would be good for a HP 1110nr mini netbook 1g memory 160g processor.

Answer (score 0):

The lightest of official Ubuntu versions is Lubuntu.
Also there is Ubuntu Netbook Edition specially designed for netbooks (discontinued currently).